# SHCreateDataObject/IDataObject Exhibits Strange Behavior During CDefView::OnBeginDrag

Tags: c++, windows, shell, com, ole

In my [IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-getuiobjectof) with **riid** == [IID_IDataObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject), I invoke [SHCreateDataObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shcreatedataobject) and supply a pointer to my newly created DataObject as such:

DataObject *pDataObject = new DataObject (this->pidl_absolute, uCount, aPidl);

```
hr = SHCreateDataObject (this->pidl_absolute, uCount, aPidl, pDataObject, riid, ppvReturn);

DataObject::DataObject (PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFolder, UINT cidl, LPCITEMIDLIST aPidl[]) : reference_count (0)
{
    ++DLL_reference_count;

    return; // DEFECT: For testing.
```

In my **DataObject::DataObject** constructor, I take care not to insert any **FORMATETC** or **STGMEDIUM**. Then I start a drag-and-drop operation from an Explorer **CDefView** window, causing the following call sequence. The drag-loop icon is mostly the "drop-effect-none" circle/slash with small [+] for some windows. For some strange reason, my **DataObject::QueryGetData** and **DataObject::SetData** are being invoked with weird arguments (with zero values that should not be zero?). Perhaps I do not understand. How could this be happening when it occurs before I have done anything that could trigger it (I think)? I wrote code to add **CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW** and **CFSTR_FILECONTENTS** to my **DataObject::DataObject** constructor, which did not work, which lead me to this problem.

**EDIT:**

After a more thorough investigation, I can conclude that my problem is not SHCreateDataObject. I only invoke this function in one place in my code:

hr = SHCreateDataObject (this->pidl_absolute, uCount, aPidl, pDataObject, riid, ppvReturn);

After invocation, there is only one format present in pDataObject: CF_SHELLIDLIST. As @SimonMourier noted, there probably should be more. I manually insert the ones I need, which, ~technically~, I should be able to do, since my NSE is virtual. I can clearly see that during the DoDragDrop() loop, Explorer is invoking my SetData with CF_HDROP with pmedium->hGlobal nullified.

The circle/slash problem no longer exists, as it was due to a bogust ReleaseStgMedium, but the nullifed hGlobal is still present.

```
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = Shell IDList Array // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL for both
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = UsingDefaultDragImage // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL for both
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = DragImageBits // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL for both
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = DragContext // tymed == TYMED_ISTREAM for both
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = DragSourceHelperFlags // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL for both
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = InShellDragLoop // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL for both
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = DragContext// tymed == TYMED_ISTREAM

DataObject.cpp(550) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = CF_HDROP // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileName // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Net Resource // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileContents // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileGroupDescriptor // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileNameMapW // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileNameMapW // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC (again)
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Shell IDList Array // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return S_OK

DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = Shell IDList Array // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL for both, all other fields of *pmedium are 0!

DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Shell Object Offsets // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = PrinterFriendlyName // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Shell IDLData Private // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = HTML Format // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileNameW // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = FileGroupDescriptorW // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Preferred DropEffect // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Performed DropEffect // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Paste Succeeded // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = UniformResourceLocator // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = InShellDragLoop // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return S_OK

DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = InShellDragLoop pformatetc->tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, *pmedium is ~ALL~ ZERO'S!!!, I return DV_E_FORMATETC

DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = DragContext // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = TargetCLSID // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Embedded Object // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Object Descriptor // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = NotRecyclable // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Logical Performed DropEffect // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Briefcase File Object // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = DropEffectFolderList // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = Autoplay Enumerated IDList Array // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = UniformResourceLocator // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = UniformResourceLocatorW // cfformat == 0, tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(552) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = AsyncFlag // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
DataObject.cpp(608) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::EnumFormatEtc
DataObject.cpp(550) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::QueryGetData : Format = CF_HDROP // tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, I return DV_E_FORMATETC
The thread 0xfc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xfa0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFD11B87D (KernelBase.dll) in explorer.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = Shell IDList Array pformatetc->tymed == TYMED_HGLOBAL, *pmedium is ~ALL~ ZERO'S!!!, not sure what to do so I lie and return S_OK without doing anything.


DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = IsShowingText
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = UsingDefaultDragImage
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = DragSourceHelperFlags
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = IsComputingImage
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = DisableDragText
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = IsComputingImage
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = DropDescription
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = DragContext
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = IsShowingLayered
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = UntrustedDragDrop
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = DropDescription
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = DisableDragText
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = DisableDragText
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = IsComputingImage
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = DropDescription
DataObject.cpp(461) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::GetData : Format = IsShowingLayered    
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = IsShowingLayered
DataObject.cpp(584) : atlTraceGeneral - DataObject::SetData : Format = IsShowingText
```

The following code shows that SHCreateDataObject injects only one FORMATETC for a filename. My guess is that format is CF_SHELLIDLIST.

```
#include <ole2.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <Shobjidl.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    OleInitialize(NULL); // clipboard needs this
    CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
    SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"C:\\Windows\\write.exe", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item));

    CComHeapPtr<ITEMID_CHILD> child;
    CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE> pidl;
    CComQIPtr<IParentAndItem>(item)->GetParentAndItem(&pidl, NULL, &child);

    CComPtr<IDataObject> dao;
    LPCITEMIDLIST list[1];
    list[0] = child;
    SHCreateDataObject(pidl, 1, list, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dao));

    OleSetClipboard(dao);

    IEnumFORMATETC* pEnumerator = 0;

    dao->EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR_GET, &pEnumerator);

    unsigned int i = 0;

    FORMATETC formatec;

    while (S_OK == pEnumerator->Next(1, &formatec, NULL))
        ++i;

    cout << "The number of formats created is: " << i << endl; // ... This printed "1".
    OleUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why don't you just call SHCreateDataObject and pass the returned object to the GetUIObjectOf caller?

Comment: @SimonMourier I need support for CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS.

Comment: @SimonMourier My strategy was to augment the default IDataObject returned by SHCreateDataObject with CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, or, alternatively, let SHCreateDataObject augment the one that I create in my DataObject::DataObject() after I have added CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS to it.

Comment: SHCreateDataObject adds these formats automatically when you use PIDLs from the file system

Comment: Indeed, it adss PIDL's for CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST, but not for CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it adds these formats, try this type of code, and check what's in the clipboard, you'll see CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS are there: https://pastebin.com/raw/wvDCVkui

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried your code (with slight modification, see EDIT), and it showed that SHCreateDataObject puts only 1 FORMATEC into the IDataObject.

Comment: Shows 6 for me. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. I managed to get past this particular bug by bypassing SHCreateDataObject altogether and inserting CF_SHELLIDLIST myself from CIDLData_CreateFromIDArray. Now I see a new bug. I will start a different question for that bug.

Comment: It's very possible Windows 7 doesn't behave like Windows 10 (which I'm using) with regards to this.